# What is the equivalent of ios-configure-glog.sh for flipper-glog?

Tags: react-native-ios, glog, flipper

I had a problem with glog in a react native app ("machine not recognised" - related to the build process getting confused about my macbook's M1 architecture). I fixed that by editing the build script in node_modules to copy in a newer version of config.sub before running ./configure. Very hacky, but it worked.

Now I have to use flipper-glog, and I have the same problem. However, I cannot find the command that is used to install flipper-glog.

Before flipper, I edited this file:

`node_modules/react-native/scripts/ios-configure-glog.sh`

I found this by looking in the glog podspec file, but I can't find that for flipper-glog. What is the equivalent for flipper-glog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ios-configure-glog.sh command is referenced by the prepare_command for plain glog, and it turns out the equivalent for flipper-glog is defined inline (at least on my machine) at:

`~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/Specs/2/7/2/Flipper-Glog/0.3.6/Flipper-Glog.podspec.json`

`2/7/2` will depend on the version of Ruby and `0.3.6` on the version of flipper.

Clearly this is some sort of cache of source maintained by cocoapods, but I don't know how/when it is updated.